# What is the Accessibility Trait, "User Interaction Enabled?" (Xcode Interface Builder)

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, accessibility, voiceover

When configuring elements within a view (.xib) for accessibility, we are given several options in the Accessibility Inspector. I understand that selecting options in the Traits section enables the user to "tab" or "swipe" through elements of a certain type when using VoiceOver. However, I'm not sure what effect selecting (or deselecting) the "User Interaction Enabled" option has.

For example, a static label has this trait enabled by default. I've enabled this element for Accessibility, populated the label and hint, and selected the Static Text and Header traits. Aside from reading the text, the user will not need to interact with this element, so I have deselected that option.

I have read Apple's "[Accessibility Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008785);" however, I'm not able to find any information regarding this trait.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the equivalent of [UIAccessibilityTraitNotEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibilitytraitnotenabled).

It's usually used for buttons or UIControls so when they are disabled VoiceOver tells the user that the element is dimmed or disabled.

Answer (score -1):

Apple goes into some detail about it here: [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622577-userinteractionenabled)

Comment: The link you provided is for UIView.userInteractionEnabled. The question was about UIAccessibilityTraits.notEnabled.